# Unordered data adding into firebase database`

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I am working with chat app where user can send images,videos and images etc.
Everything is working fine but when i am adding video path into firebase database it added in third row each time but others data added in my ordered way. As you can see in image below `Message` and `Image_Message` is always added first but in video case `Video_Message` added on third row. How can i move it like `Message` or `Image_Message` on first Place.

[image: Firebase Database]

Here is my way to add video data into firebase database

```
Uri download_URI = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                            map.put("Message_From",  userSession.getUserFname() + " " +  userSession.getUserLname());
                            map.put("Message_To", UserName_Intent);
                            map.put("Video_Message", download_URI.toString());
                            map.put("Time", time);
                            map.put("token_From",Sender_FCMToken);
                            map.put("token_To",FirebaseToken_Intent);
                            String Temp_Key =  databaseReference.push().getKey();
                            Map<String, Object> RoomKey = new HashMap<>();
                            databaseReference.updateChildren(RoomKey);
                            DatabaseReference message_Root =  databaseReference.child(Temp_Key);
                            message_Root.updateChildren(map);
```

Adding Image data into firebase

```
 Uri download_URI = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("Message_From", userSession.getUserFname() + " " + userSession.getUserLname());
                map.put("Message_To", UserName_Intent);
                map.put("Image_Message", download_URI.toString());
                map.put("Time", time);
                map.put("token_From",Sender_FCMToken);
                map.put("token_To",FirebaseToken_Intent);
                String Temp_Key = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                Map<String, Object> RoomKey = new HashMap<>();
                databaseReference.updateChildren(RoomKey);
                DatabaseReference message_Root = databaseReference.child(Temp_Key);
                message_Root.updateChildren(map);
```

Comment: It doesn't matter with what is your ordering. Eventually you are fetching data using the key value pair from HashMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties of a node in the Firebase Database console are shown in alphabetical order. This can't be modified.

But, as mzeus commented, this doesn't usually matter, since the only display your users see is in the app, where you control the order in which the properties are shown.

Comment: I changed `Video_Message` to `Message_aVideo` but still it added into 3rd row as above if its by alphabetical order then it should placed in first row.

Comment: Case matters: [lowercase `a` is after uppercase `M`](http://www.asciitable.com/).